# What techniques are used for limiting lists to active items except when an inactive item needs to be included for historical purposes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ui-design

For example, let's say I have 3 possible project statuses,

1. Open
2. Closed
3. Inactive

Let's pretend I've created two projects, one with a status of "Open" and the other with status of "Inactive." Then, somewhere down the road, the status "Inactive" is no longer pertinent so it is deactivated via some "IsActive" flag in the table of statuses. This causes it to no longer show up in the list of statuses bound to a DropDownList or equivalent list.

So, now when users create new project items, the "Add New" screen should only show the two active statuses, Open and Closed. But now let's say they are editing past projects whose statuses may no longer be active and available. What techniques are used to include the inactive status in the list, at least until they have re-saved using an active status? (Though I would probably allow re-saving with the older status.)

I see a few options, but having never solved this problem before I'm not sure which would be the easiest to maintain:

1. Always select all possible statuses from the repository, and in managed code, filter out the inactives except for the status currently set on the project, and bind using this list.
2. Select only active statuses from the repository and append (merge), in managed code, the status from the project into the list, and bind with this list.
3. Pass an identifier for the project through to the SQL that retrieves the statuses and use it to UNION the project's current status to the list of active statuses, and bind using this list.

Each seems like it would be fairly trivial to implement, but like I said, I'm not experienced with this situation. I have several lists of items that can be activated/deactivated through maintenance screens available to administrators; some will remain rather static, but a few will grow indefinitely large. Options 2 and 3 would be the most efficient when the lists grow rather large, but option 1 seems like it might be the easiest to implement.

I'm more concerned about time than I am about performance that this point. I'm working on an ASP.NET application, .NET 2.0, C#, web forms for the UI and (I/My)Batis.NET for the data layer, which talks to a SQL Server database.

What would you suggest I do, gods of StackOverflow?

Comment: Punt. Don't let them "deactivate" a status if there are "active" records that have it.

Comment: @Anthony: I've thought about that, but at some point these "Projects" are forever "Closed", never to be edited again. The debate I'm having with myself is whether I should even be reusing the UI for closed items, as they don't need to be editable any more. Know what I'm saying?

Answer (score 0):

I typically use following approach:

1. The method that retrieves status values will take an optional parameter (or have an overload in .NET 2.0~3.5) that will specify whether to fetch inactive values or not. So you have a choice to fetch only active statuses or all statues - use as per your need.
2. Many times, all statuses are fetched because the screen will be used for add/edit/view purpose. However, add/edit/view dialogs are launched at client side w/o any post-backs. So status drop-down will have all status values and inactive values will be decorated with certain CSS class so that they appear in red color to indicate being inactive. In add mode,  js code (using jquery) will hide inactive status values. Of course, there are validations in back-end business logic to check validity of status code.